# TYPO3 extensions with good tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, typo3

I am looking for a TYPO3 extensions with good test examples - unit tests, functional etc. By good I mean - test that covers possibly lot of code and are up to date so I can actually execute them without fixing anything upfront.

Here some examples which I check:

- news 7.0.7 - 261 tests, 14 failed
- realurl 2.4.0 - fails to execute
- femanager 4.2.2 - fails to execute
- devlog 3.0.2 - fails to execute
- cs_seo 3.0.2 - fails to execute
- aoe_ipauth 1.1.0 - fails to execute

Comment: https://github.com/codappix/search_core/ and https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr should hopefully work.

Both need either elasticsearch or solr for functional tests.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout extensions from Oliver Klee, who started 2009 to implement tests in TYPO3 core.

- oelib https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/oelib/
- realty https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/realty/
- seminars https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/seminars/

Also have a look at his example extension 'ext_tea' at Github https://github.com/oliverklee/ext-tea.
A TYPO3 example extension for unit testing and best practices.
Oliver Klee is giving workshops, and has more examples on Github.

Christian Kuhn implemented a view days ago the possibility in TYPO3 9.5 to run Tests using Docker. Documentation is in progress
Run `Build/Scripts/runTests.sh -h` to see what is possible.